# @Simple_form rendering but not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just switched to rails and started on my first application. Im struggling a bit with the forms and bootstrap however! 
It says my form is rendering and Im not receiving any errors, but none of my form code is showing.
Im running rails 4.2.5 with the latest bootstrap-sass and simple_form versions.
Im not sure whether my bootstrap css is actually working at all either, it doesnt appear to be. Been trying different versions, installing and uninstalling and changing the code for hours but canẗ seem to get it working. Would be immensely grateful for help!

Kind regards,
Jens

Form (_form.html.erb) code;

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, html: ({ cĺass:'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<div class = "field">
<%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :author %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

I renamed my application.css to .scss, it now contains only;
`@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";`
 application.js contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after you install bootstrap and simple_form?

Answer (score 0):

your code is a partial so where are you calling it from? It needs to be rendered inside of another file like index.html.erb.

Whenever the name starts with a _ it means its a partial not a full page, its to be rendered inside another page.

Also there's a div that doesn't end in your code but why even use a div for a class when you can pass that in through Rails ? class: "field" or something along those lines.

Comment: **You don't need an equal sign for the first line that might be the issue.** You are wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the resulting html source and looking for one of the inputs to make sure that it's really getting rendered. If it is than the problem may be that you're missing a closing div for your `<div class = "field">`.

If not then I would suggest you take a look at your `new.html.erb` (or wherever your rendering your partial and making sure you have something like:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Notice that the `=` is important here. If you're missing this it could be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/views/books/new.html.erb
<%= render "form", locals: { book: @book } %>

#app/views/books/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for book, html: ({ cĺass:'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
   <%= f.input :description %>
   <%= f.input :author %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above should make sure you're outputting a valid form (HTML).

---

If you're still not seeing the form appear, it will *likely* be a CSS issue. The difference being that CSS gives *styling* definition to HTML.

As mention in other answers, the solution to this lies in the *classes* you're giving to your HTML elements. Since you're using `bootstrap`, it means you have to first ensure you have `bootstrap` installed and loaded.

You can use [`rails-assets`](http://rails-assets.org) to pull from the `bootstrap` repo directly:

```
#Gemfile
source "https://rails-assets.org"
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap', ">= 4.0.0.alpha"

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
@import bootstrap
```

--

If you wanted to test your HTML/CSS directly, you need to remove the `class: "form-horizontal"` class from your HTML. If this shows the form, it means your CSS is incorrect, in which case I'd recommend you post back on here with it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot guys! I got it to work, I had simply forgotten the "=" before render! The other oddities were just last minute tired scrabbling in an attempt to make it work. :P Again, thanks a ton for your help guys!